# How to lower/higher one surface without the neighboring surface making weird stuff

Tags: modeling

I am currently building a ship model (18 century british navy ...) and I have a question ... 
I have looked at mirroring, so that my object is mirrored and I do not have to worry about forgetting an vertex or sth. similar. 
[image]

I want to higher the back part (with the marked edge).
However, when I do so 
[image]

this happens. 
I want the rotated surface to stay down (I otice only now, that I need mor room for the quarter deck, but that's not the problem here ... :-D ) 
This object does not need to be very precise, it is for a concept work (maybe I'll stretch it and improve some other stuff ... but basics first, right? :-D )
SIne I have worked with maya before, sadly not a student anymore, one could do this simply by exxpanding it, with blender, I have some trouble figuring out, how to do this ... 
any help would be highly appreciated, 
Karanda (yes, a David Eddings fan)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called extruding in Blender (and most other 3d software).

Select the faces you want to extrude in edit mode and press <kbd>E</kbd>. In this case, the face will extrude along the z-axis. press <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to confirm the position.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe disable or apply the mirror modifer and hide the faces you dont want to move.

You could also just use proportional editing.